# reverse usb tethering in strict dns environment

Tags: linux, usb, dns, android, dnsmasq

In the environment, all DNS query is blocked by firewall. And wifi or 3G is not allowed

I want to let a rooted Android(192.168.42.2) accessing internet by plug usb on PC(192.168.42.1 for usb0 interface).
The PC can connect to internet eth0(192.168.1.1) by a static IP DNS(eg. 192.168.1.53) (don't allow other dns access).

```
# in PC linux, this is workable (nameserver=192.168.1.53) 
ping 173.194.72.99 # workable for www.google.com's IP
ping www.google.com # failed because even
```

It is possible to ping internet ip inside Android.
But I can not access dns query.

```
ping 173.194.72.99 # workable for www.google.com's IP
ping www.google.com # failed because even
```

I've setup a dnsmasq on the PC(linux OS), it can query DNS on the PC.
But it can not query DNS inside the android.

```
# in Anddroid's busybox nslookup, the usage is nslookup <host> <server>
nslookup www.google.com 192.168.1.53 # failed
nslookup www.google.com 192.168.42.1 # failed
```

The reverse usb tethering method is following this post http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2287494. After enable adb debug & USB tethering on Android, I setup as following:

```
root@android:/ # netstat -rn
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address          Foreign Address        State
 tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:7777         0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
 tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:53           0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
 tcp       0      0 192.168.42.129:53      0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
 udp       0      0 127.0.0.1:53           0.0.0.0:*              CLOSE
 udp       0      0 192.168.42.129:53      0.0.0.0:*              CLOSE
 udp       0      0 0.0.0.0:67             0.0.0.0:*              CLOSE
1|root@android:/ # ps |grep dns
nobody    8608  115   1028   492   c00ec9e0 400da624 S /system/bin/dnsmasq

1|root@android:/ # ifconfig rndis0 192.168.42.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
1|root@android:/ # route add default gw 192.168.42.1 dev rndis0
1|root@android:/ # ping -c 1 8.8.8.8  # workable
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get the picture correct as you didn't post mask and gateway info but I think that you simply don't have DNS server setup on the Android interface.

The easiest way I can think of is to setup Google DNS servers

so on the Android it would be:

IP: 192.168.42.2
Mask: 255.255.255.0
gtw: 192.168.42.1

DNS: 8.8.8.8
     8.8.4.4

Verify you can ping the DNS IP before using the settings but you say above you can...

Comment: Sorry, I describe it more. The problem is port 53 of 8.8.8.8 is blockked in my network environment. I'm trying to use dns query inside Android both server query are failed

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.

Simply restarting the DNS server got it working for me.
I realized that it was started via dhcp from a older network connection

```
    22104 dhcp      1164 S    /system/bin/dnsmasq --keep-in-foreground --no-resolv --no-poll --dhcp-option-force=43,ANDROID_METERED --dhcp-authoritative --pid-file  --dhcp-range=192.168.42.2,192.168.42.254,12h --dhcp-range=192.
```

So I simply killed 22104 and restarted dnsmasq as root - got it working :)